# How to specify the address of a json file in a script in the view

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, razor

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project and have a script like the following and I now in the URL, I'm reading a json file from a an address but I downloaded the json file and put it into my project (wwwroot_>JS files) and I want the URL to read from that file. But I don't know how to specify the address of my json file which is lying in src="~/js/Persian.json" in my project.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datatables.min.js"></script>



<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({

            //"searching": false,
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Persian.json"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use global config for datatable like:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    responsive: true,
    ... other global configs 
   language: {
        "url": "/Js/Persian.json"
      }
 }
```

its work in .net core mvc, also you can translate default lang:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
language:
{
    "sEmptyTable": "موردی برای نمایش یافت نشد",
    "sInfo": "نمایش _START_ تا _END_ از مجموع _TOTAL_ مورد",
    "sInfoEmpty": "موردی برای نمایش در دسترس نمی باشد",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(فیلتر شده از مجموع _MAX_ مورد)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ".",
    "sLengthMenu": "تعداد در صفحه _MENU_ ",
    "sLoadingRecords": "درحال بارگذاری...",
    "sProcessing": "درحال پردازش...",
    "sSearch": "جستجو : ",
    "sZeroRecords": "موردی یافت نشد",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "ابتدا",
        "sPrevious": "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'>",
        "sNext": "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'>",
        "sLast": "انتها"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": مرتب سازی به صورت صعودی",
        "sSortDescending": ": مرتب سازی به صورت نزولی"
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just finished my local testing. Inside my `Scripts` directory I included the `Spanish.json` file.

[image]

And I just called it this way

```
"language": { "url": "/Scripts/Spanish.json" }
```

Notice that removed the **~** character that you included in your example.

And here's the result:
[image]

If that doesn't work you can specify manually the values in your jQuery DataTable's options, like this:

```js
 $('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
       "sProcessing":   "درحال پردازش...",
       "sLengthMenu":   "نمایش محتویات _MENU_",
       "sZeroRecords":  "موردی یافت نشد",
       "sInfo":         "نمایش _START_ تا _END_ از مجموع _TOTAL_ مورد",
       "sInfoEmpty":    "تهی",
       "sInfoFiltered": "(فیلتر شده از مجموع _MAX_ مورد)",
       "sInfoPostFix":  "",
       "sSearch":       "جستجو:",
       "sUrl":          "",
       "oPaginate": {
           "sFirst":    "ابتدا",
           "sPrevious": "قبلی",
           "sNext":     "بعدی",
           "sLast":     "انتها"
       }
   }
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Tiger</td>
          <td>Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>5421</td>
          <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Garrett</td>
          <td>Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>8422</td>
          <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Ashton</td>
          <td>Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
          <td>1562</td>
          <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works for me as well but when the internet is not connected I want the url reads from the json local file.

Comment: UPS! I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. Let me try in a local application, please

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the addressing method you mentioned in your answer didn't work for me, so I forced to put all language words in my script.

Comment: @MinaMRM: I just saw that you're using MVC core. I tested in MVC 5. Maybe there is something more to setup in MVC Core in order to work as it did in MVC 5.